# App react-native: Generated a random token, but impossible to retrieve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

(Question posted using a translator).

My problem is quite simple: I generate a random token upon the user's login, but it's impossible for me to retrieve it (I should specify that the token expires after about an hour and that with each login, a unique and random token is generated to increase the security of the application).

Therefore, the login works quite well; I retrieve the user ID obtained at registration with the username. Once registered, it is possible to log in with the email and password.

I will present my code to you.

**The jwt file that allows me to generate my token:**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  //
  generateTokenForUser: function (userData) {
    // génération du token
    return jwt.sign(
      {
        // données encodées dans le token
        userId: userData.id,
        isAdmin: userData.isAdmin,
      },
      // clé secrète pour l'encodage
      process.env.JWT_SIGN_SECRET,
      {
        // durée de validité du token
        expiresIn: "1h",
      },
    );
  },
  parseAuthorization: function (authorization) {
    // récupération du token
    return authorization != null ? authorization.replace("Bearer ", "") : null;
  },
  getUserid: function (authorization) {
    // récupération de l'ID utilisateur
    const jwttoken = module.exports.parseAuthorization(authorization);
    console.log(jwttoken);
    if (jwttoken != null) {
      try {
        // vérification du token
        const jwtToken = jwt.verify(jwttoken, process.env.JWT_SIGN_SECRET);
        if (jwtToken && jwtToken.userId) {
          // si le token est valide, on retourne l'ID utilisateur
          return jwtToken.userId;
        } else {
          // Sinon, renvoyez une erreur
          throw new Error("ID d'utilisateur manquant dans le jeton JWT");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // Sinon, renvoyez une erreur
        throw new Error("Erreur de vérification du jeton utilisateur");
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Jetons identification non valides");
    }
  },
  generateTemporaryToken: function (userId) {
    return jwt.sign(
      {
        userId: userId,
        // Autres données éventuelles
      },
      process.env.TEMPORARY_TOKEN_SECRET, // Clé secrète spécifique pour les tokens temporaires
      {
        expiresIn: "15m", // Durée de validité du token temporaire (30 minutes)
      },
    );
  },
  parseTemporaryToken: function (temporaryToken) {
    // récupération du token
    return temporaryToken != null
      ? temporaryToken.replace("Bearer ", "")
      : null;
  },
};
```

**The AuthContext file where I store the information:**

```
// src/context/AuthContext.js

// Importation des dépendances nécessaires
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

// Création du contexte d'authentification
export const AuthContext = createContext();

// Composant fournisseur du contexte d'authentification
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // État pour suivre si l'utilisateur est connecté ou non
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [userPseudo, setUserPseudo] = useState(null);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);

  // Fonction pour connecter l'utilisateur
  const login = async (user) => {
    const userToken = await generateTokenForUser(user);
    localStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken);

    setUserLoggedIn(true);
    setUserId(user.id);
    setUserPseudo(user.pseudo);
    setUserToken(userToken);
  };

  // Fonction pour déconnecter l'utilisateur
  const logOut = () => {
    //localStorage.removeItem('userToken');

    setUserLoggedIn(false);
    setUserId(null);
    setUserPseudo(null);
    setUserData(null);
    setUserToken(null);
  };

  // Fonction pour mettre à jour le pseudo de l'utilisateur
  const updateUserPseudo = (pseudo) => {
    setUserPseudo(pseudo);
  };

  // Fonction pour définir l'ID de l'utilisateur dans le contexte d'authentification
  const setAuthContextUserId = (id) => {
    setUserId(id);
  };

  // Fournir l'état et les fonctions associées aux composants enfants via le contexte
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      isUserLoggedIn, userId, userPseudo, userData, userToken, setUserToken,
      updateUserPseudo, setUserLoggedIn, setUserId, setAuthContextUserId, setUserPseudo, setUserData,
      login, logOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Here are the files that require a token: homeLocationctrl:**

```
// importation des modules
const { homelocation } = require("../Models");
const jwt = require("../utils/jwt");

module.exports = {
  newlocations: async (req, res) => {
    // récupération du header d'authentification
    try {
      console.log("Nouvelle requête de création de lieu.");

      const headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
      const userId = jwt.getUserid(headerAuth);

      console.log("ID de l'utilisateur extrait du token :", userId);

      /**
       * Finds a user's home location by their user ID.
       * @async
       * @function
       * @param {number} userId - The user ID to search for.
       * @returns {Promise<object>} - A Promise that resolves with the user's home location object if found, or null if not found.
       */
      const userFound = await homelocation.findOne({
        where: { homeID: userId },
      });

      const { namelocation, infolocation, adresslocation } = req.body;

      console.log("Données reçues de la requête :", req.body);

      if (!namelocation || !infolocation || !adresslocation) {
        console.log("Paramètres manquants.");
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Paramètres manquants" });
      }

      if (namelocation.length < 5 || namelocation.length > 20) {
        console.log("Le nom du lieu ne respecte pas la longueur requise.");
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Le nom du lieu doit être compris entre 5 et 20 caractères",
        });
      }

      if (infolocation.length < 5 || infolocation.length > 350) {
        console.log("Les informations ne respectent pas la longueur requise.");
        return res.status(400).json({
          error:
            "Les informations doivent être comprises entre 5 et 350 caractères",
        });
      }

      if (adresslocation.length < 5 || adresslocation.length > 100) {
        console.log("L'adresse ne respecte pas la longueur requise.");
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "L'adresse doit être comprise entre 5 et 100 caractères",
        });
      }

      homelocation
        .create({
          homeID: userId,
          namelocation,
          infolocation,
          adresslocation,
        })
        .then(function (newLocation) {
          console.log("Nouvelle location créée :", newLocation);
          return res.status(201).json({
            locationID: newLocation.homeID,
            message: "Nouvelle location créée",
          });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Erreur lors de la création de la location :", err);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Erreur inattendue : merci de recommencer" });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur inattendue :", error);
    }
  },

  // route getlocations
  getlocations: async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Requête GET reçue pour /api/homelocation/getloc");
    try {
      console.log("Nouvelle requête pour obtenir les lieux de l'utilisateur.");

      const headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
      console.log("Token reçu depuis le client :", headerAuth);
      const userId = jwt.getUserid(headerAuth);

      console.log("ID de l'utilisateur extrait du token :", userId);

      homelocation
        .findAll({
          where: { homeID: userId },
        })
        .then(function (userFound) {
          // retour si l'utilisateur existe déjà
          if (userFound && userFound.length > 0) {
            console.log("Voici les résultats");
            return res.status(200).json(userFound);
          } else {
            console.log("L'utilisateur n'a pas de lieu enregistrer");
            return res
              .status(404)
              .json({ error: "L'utilisateur n'a pas de lieu enregistrer pour le moment" });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération des lieux :", err);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Impossible de récupérer les lieux" });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur inattendue :", error);
    }
  },

  // route updatelocations
  updatelocations: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log("Nouvelle requête de modification de lieu.");

      const headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
      const userId = jwt.getUserid(headerAuth);

      console.log("ID de l'utilisateur extrait du token :", userId);

      homelocation
        .findOne({
          where: { homeID: userId },
        })
        .then(function (userFound) {
          if (userFound) {
            userFound
              .update({
                namelocation: req.body.namelocation,
                infolocation: req.body.infolocation,
                adresslocation: req.body.adresslocation,
              })
              .then(function () {
                console.log("Location modifié avec succès.");
                return res.status(201).json({ message: "Lieu modifié" });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Erreur lors de la modification du lieu :", err);
                return res
                  .status(500)
                  .json({ error: "Impossible de modifier le lieu" });
              });
          } else {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "Le lieu n'existe pas" });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Erreur lors de la modification du lieu :", err);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Impossible de modifier le lieu" });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur inattendue :", error);
    }
  },

  // route deletelocations
  deletelocations: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log("Nouvelle requête de suppression de lieu.");

      const headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
      const userId = jwt.getUserid(headerAuth);

      console.log("ID de l'utilisateur extrait du token :", userId);

      const userFound = await homelocation.findOne({
        where: { homeID: userId },
      });

      if (!userFound) {
        console.log("Le lieu n'existe pas.");
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Le lieu n'existe pas" });
      }

      userFound
        .destroy()
        .then(function () {
          console.log("Lieu supprimé avec succès.");
          return res.status(201).json({ message: "Lieu supprimé" });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Erreur lors de la suppression du lieu :", err);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Impossible de supprimer le lieu" });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur inattendue :", error);
    }
  },
};
```

**Location:**

```
// src/navigation/location.js

// Importations nécessaires
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import locationStyle from '../styles/locationStyle';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import { get } from 'react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry';

function LocationScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { userId, userToken, userPseudo } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);
  const [showDeleteButton, setShowDeleteButton] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Token mis à jour :", userToken);
    if (!userId) return;
    // Charger les locations depuis l'API
    const loadUserLocations = async () => {
      console.log("Page Mes Location ID:", userId, "- Username:", userPseudo, "- Token:", userToken)

        // Vérifier si le userToken est vide
  if (!userToken || userToken.trim() === '') {
    console.log("Le token de l'utilisateur est absent ou vide.");
    // Ici, tu pourrais renvoyer une erreur ou demander à l'utilisateur de se reconnecter
    return; // Arrêter l'exécution si le token n'est pas valide
  }

      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.17:3000/api/homelocation/getloc?userId=${userId}`, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`, // userToken provient de ton AuthContext
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });

        console.log('Réponse brute:', response);

        // Vérifiez le statut HTTP de la réponse
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setLocations(data);
        } else {
          console.error('Erreur de statut:', response.status);

          // Log de la réponse pour le debug
          const text = await response.text();
          console.log('Réponse brute:', text);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erreur lors du chargement des emplacements', error.message);
      }
    };

    loadUserLocations();
  }, [userId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.locationTitle && !locations.includes(route.params?.locationTitle)) {
      setLocations(prev => [...prev, route.params?.locationTitle]);
    }
  }, [route.params?.locationTitle]);

  // Fonction pour gérer la suppression d'une location
  const handleDeleteLocation = async (item) => {
    try {
      await fetch(`http://192.168.1.17:3000/homelocation/deleteloc`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: item.id }),
      });
      setLocations((prevLocations) => prevLocations.filter((location) => location.id !== item.id));
    }  catch (error) {
      console.error('Erreur lors de la suppression de l\'emplacement', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={locationStyle.container}>
      <Button
        title="Ajouter une nouvelle location"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('CreateLocation');
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={locations}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={locationStyle.listItem}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate('UiInterface');
              }}
            >
              <Text style={locationStyle.text}>{item.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={locationStyle.buttonsContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={locationStyle.button}
                onPress={() => {
                  // Mettre en place la logique de modification ici
                }}
              >
                <Text style={locationStyle.buttonText}>Modifier</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              {showDeleteButton && (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={locationStyle.button}
                  onPress={() => {
                    handleDeleteLocation(item);
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{ ...locationStyle.buttonText, color: 'red' }}>Supprimer</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => (item.id ? item.id.toString() : Math.random().toString())}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default LocationScreen;
```

Here are the logs at login:

```
 LOG  Code de statut: 200
 LOG  Données envoyées: {"email": "zana@gmail.com", "password": "Bisous5910*", "username": ""}     
 LOG  Mot de passe envoyé: Bisous5910*
 LOG  Réponse du serveur: {"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImlzQWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlLCJpYXQiOjE2OTkwMDcxNjksImV4cCI6MTY5OTAxMDc2OX0.wQC54F4SkJEIPO4h1ZOtUhuHCBT3Lbf1gAzzliIeED0", "userId": 1, "username": "Zana-S"}
```

When I click on a button named "My Rentals," I need to retrieve the rentals created by the user, but to do that, I must retrieve the token that is associated with the ID in the database.

```
LOG  Bouton Mes Location
LOG  Token mis à jour : null
LOG  Page Mes Location ID: 1 - Username: Zana-S - Token: null
LOG  Le token de l'utilisateur est absent ou vide.
```